# Dawn4 build error - eosio.token/eosio.token.wast.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: wasm, compilation

I was able to run Dawn 3, but ran into a snag with Dawn 4:
Using a fresh CentOS7 VM in VirtualBox, building the dawn-v4.0.0 tag using the eosio_build.sh:

```
[ 80% ] Building CXX object libraries/testing/CmakeFiles/chain_tester.dir/test.cpp.o
/home/eos/eos/libraries/testing/test.cpp:4:10: fatal error: eosio.token/eosio.token.wast.hpp: No such file or directory
#include <eosio.token/eosio.token.wast.hpp>
compilation terminated.
```

I think output products were not created for the token contract.  Looking under build/contracts I see that only the eosio.bios contract has .wast, .wast.hpp, .wasm but the other contracts under build only have the .abi output.

Mostly curious if anyone else ran into this or if it's just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error, and filed a bug (which has been assigned).

A short-term fix supplied by someone, which seems to work: go into `build/contracts`, run `make`, return to top level and run the original build script again.

Comment: running make on the build directory worked for me on 4.0